# What is it called for the part of a hill where it discontinuously gets steeper?

Tags: terminology

What is it called for the part of a hill where it discontinuously gets steeper? If you climbing an easy slope and encounter a new steeper slope (such as formed by a rocky hill and accompanying soil slopes leading up to it), is this change called anything?

Comment: Cliff, if steep enough?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no single term to describe the sudden **change** in the gradient of a slope. Personally I would describe it simply as a *sudden increase in slope*. However there are many words to describe the landforms that occur when gradient sharply increase.

Terms such as *cliff, escarpment* and *mountainside* all describe the steep landform as whole. Whereas terms such as *flank* or *face* describe the side of the hill only with a steep gradient.

You might find this link particularly helpful:
https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/parts-and-features-of-mountains-hills-and-cliffs

Comment: *meeting the flank* best name

Answer (score 3):

It's called a 'break in slope' or a '[break of slope](http://www.hyperdictionary.com/dictionary/break-in-slope)'.

Comment: I believe this answer and to an extent, Matt's answer are both correct.  I have encountered slope break in describing a significant slope change when on a convex surface, such as a plateau to escarpment, but never on a significant slope change on a concave surface, such as a rock face to talus fan.

Comment: My old man was an Oregon forester and surveyor.  His term for what you describe was the "toe" of the slope.